# Specify count column with left outer join in linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-entities, left-join

I am using EF with code first and migrations. I have two entities:

```cs
public class LicensedSoftware
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
    public int SoftwareDetailId { get; set; }
}

public class SoftwareDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
    public string SoftwareName { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to specify the column to count on when doing a left outer join but it seems to only use `Count(*)`.

Here is my linq:

```cs
SoftwareDetails
.GroupJoin(LicensedSoftwares, l => l.Id, c => c.SoftwareDetailId, 
    (l, c) => 
        new { Licensed = l, Details = c.DefaultIfEmpty() })
.SelectMany(x => x.Details, (x, merged) => new { Details = merged, x.Licensed })
.GroupBy(x => x.Licensed, x => x.Details, 
    (key, g) => 
        new { Licensed = key, Count = g.Count() })
```

The generated SQL is:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Count]
, [t0].[Id], [t0].[FamilyName], [t0].[SoftwareName], [t0].[Version]
FROM [SoftwareDetails] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [LicensedSoftwares] AS [t1] ON [t0].[Id] = [t1].[SoftwareDetailId]
GROUP BY [t0].[Id], [t0].[FamilyName], [t0].[SoftwareName], [t0].[Version]
```

Which will also count the row from the SoftwareDetails table so I will always have a count of at least 1.

I would like for it to be (notice the count in the select):

```sql
SELECT COUNT([t1].[Id]) AS [Count]
, [t0].[Id], [t0].[FamilyName], [t0].[SoftwareName], [t0].[Version]
FROM [SoftwareDetails] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [LicensedSoftwares] AS [t1] ON [t0].[Id] = [t1].[SoftwareDetailId]
GROUP BY [t0].[Id], [t0].[FamilyName], [t0].[SoftwareName], [t0].[Version]
```

The closest to the correct results I get is with this:

```cs
SoftwareDetails
    .Select (sd => new 
    { 
        sd.Id, sd.FamilyName, sd.SoftwareName, sd.Version, 
        Count = LicensedSoftwares
                    .Where(ls => ls.SoftwareDetailId == sd.Id && ls.Id != null)
                    .Count()
    })
```

but I don't like the SQL that this generates:

```sql
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[FamilyName], [t0].[SoftwareName], [t0].[Version], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [LicensedSoftwares] AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[SoftwareDetailId] = [t0].[Id]
) AS [Count]
FROM [SoftwareDetails] AS [t0]
```

Does anyone know to get EF to use a specific column in the count instead of all columns?

Answer (score 0):

Off Topic Question: Shouldn't the SoftwareDetail be the child and LicencedSoftware be the parent, so the forieng key to be other way round?

Irrelevant of my question, please try the below out:

```
 var query = from softwareDetail in context.SoftwareDetails
                        join licensedSoftware in context.LicensedSoftwares
                            on softwareDetail.Id equals licensedSoftware.SoftwareDetailId
                        select new { softwareDetail, licensedSoftware }
                            into temp
                            group temp by temp.softwareDetail into temp2
                            select new { temp2, count = temp2.Count() };
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't generate the desired sql. This also does an `inner join`.

Comment: how about you tell me the exact SQL statement and I help you translate into a LINQ query

Comment: I did. I stated the generated sql and then what I wanted replaced.

Comment: When I get back to a computer, I'll update the post.

Comment: if you do a left join and want to know how many successful (ie, not null) left joins result are, then what is the difference between you do an inner join and count the whole result set (which is what it was doing by my LINQ)?

Comment: also if you know the exact sql, you are able to put the SQL directly without letting the QueryProvider (in this case, Entity framework) to generate for you. check this code snippet I did:  **using (var context = new LogCollectorModel(CreateForeFrontEntityModelConnectionString(server, catalog)))
            {
                var calcTasks = context.CalcTaskIdHostNames.SqlQuery(sql);}**  you can put the SQL query in there and do a count in the end